# Pandas: Merge two rows if row contains certain string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sheet that looks like this.

| Fleet Risk Control | Communication | Interpersonal relationships | Demographic | Demographic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q_21086 | Q_21087 | Q_21088 | AGE | GENDER |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 27 | Male |

What I'm trying to achieve is where there is a row with 'Q_' inside of it, merge that cell with the top row and return a new dataframe.

So the existing data above would become something like this:

| Fleet Risk Control - Q_21086 | Communication - Q_21087 | Interpersonal relationships - Q_21088 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |

I honestly have no idea where to even begin with something like this.

Comment: Can there only be 1 or 0 rows with "Q_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one. This is for input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fleet Risk Control': ['Q_21086', 1],
              'Communication': ['Q_21087', 3],
              'Interpersonal relationships': ['Q_21088', 4],
              'Demographic': ['AGE', 27],
              'Demographic 2': ['Gender', 'Male']})
```

Now concat the header line with the first line of df:

```
df.columns = df.columns + ' - ' + df.iloc[0, :]
```

Extract every line without the first and dropping the last both columns

```
df = df.iloc[1:, :-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# rename columns
df.columns = [x + ' - ' + y if y.startswith('Q_') else x for x, y in zip(df.columns, df.iloc[0])]

#drop not matching columns
to_drop = [c for c, _ in df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: not x.startswith('Q_')).items() if _]
df.drop(to_drop, axis=1)[1:]
```